# Bash, convert IP address in batch

Tags: macos, bash, ip, dig

I wanna convert a list of domain to the IP address using bash scripts in OSX.

I created a list file to present the domain line by line like this

```
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.facebook.com
```

I used the following scripts to lookup the IP address:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r domain
do
    echo `dig +short $domain` 
done < list
```

where list is a file that contains those domain.

However, it end up only show a empty string.

But when I only query one domain, the command is okay.

```
dig +short www.google.com
> 216.58.221.132
```

Hope anyone can help me to figure out the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you drop the `echo` part and just perform a `dig +short $domain`? The `echo` is probably returning the return value of the call of `dig`.

Comment: I tried to drop the echo part and it also returned empty string

Comment: Without changing anything, your example works fine for me in OSX...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dig` has the `-f` command line option to read a list of domain names from a file. From the manpage,

> The **-f** option makes **dig** operate in batch mode by reading a list of lookup requests to process from the file **filename**. The file contains a number of queries, one per line. Each entry in the file should be organized in the same way they would be presented as queries to **dig** using the command-line interface.

Running

```
dig +short -f list
```

where the file named list contains

```
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.facebook.com
```

will give you output like

```
74.125.239.114
74.125.239.112
74.125.239.116
74.125.239.113
74.125.239.115
fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com.
206.190.36.45
206.190.36.105
star.c10r.facebook.com.
31.13.77.6
```

Comment: The answer is perfect! Thank you!